# Get index from Node event stream split()

Tags: node.js, event-stream

I'm building a Node script using `event-stream` that iterates through a file line-by-line via the `split()` method and I would like to reference the line number in the resulting output. Is this possible in my implementation?

```

```
var s = fs.createReadStream(entry.fullPath)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line) {
        // How can I get line number here?
})
```

```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this but maybe there is a better way.

```
var lineNumber = 0;

var s = fs.createReadStream(entry.fullPath)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line) {
        console.log(lineNumber, line);
        lineNumber++;
})
```